# I am developing a website on a Mac, and all major browsers render it correctly. However I am stumped as to how to make it display properly in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-float, margins

Here is the website: http://dev.oonasboston.com

In IE, it renders without some of the headers, the logo shifts to the right, the menu stacks the links one above the other (instead of side-by-side), and the it appears as though the margin in the footer content aren't reading correctly.

I would like to figure out how to fix this problem.  I am happy with the way it displays in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari.

I am using Wordpress and using my own css.

Comment: If the HTML doesn't validate, you'll have nothing but problems with Explorer.  I checked and you are missing a `doctype` which is also a big problem for Explorer.  See http://validator.w3.org

Comment: When you go to the website, view the page's source. I don't know what you've done, but you have weird/duplicate IE conditional comments and things are a little messy

Answer (score 3):

More than anything else, for cross browser compatibility, the doctype declaration (`<!doctype html>`, for example) should be the very first line of your source.[*****](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/)

http://validator.w3.org/ would have notified you of this, and likely other things. (http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/ for CSS.)

So, you’ll need to find the WordPress header file where that code is and alter it. You can get help doing that at http://webchat.freenode.net/?nick=stephanie&channels=#wordpress should you require it.

Comment: Yeah, I just switched it in Developer Tools to force it out of Quirks Mode, and it works much better. This is your answer, @user1993971

Comment: More specifically, I would say delete the first 16 lines (down to and including `<html xmlns...`) and replace with only `<!doctype html>`

Comment: @DavidJohnSmith Yeah you can't just do that. Whether it's wordpress or some specific library, the class on the `<html>` may or may not be important

Comment: Also add `<head>` tag on line 22

Comment: @Ian It's the same conditional `html`s repeated below that, so I would say with confidence that you can "just do that"